# Given a connection on a principal bundle, two definitions of covariant derivatives on an associated vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, principal-bundles

Suppose $\pi:P\to X$ is a principal $G$-bundle with a connection $1$-form $\omega$, $\rho:G\to \text{GL}(V)$ is a linear representation (where $V$ is a finite-dimensional real vector space), and $E:=P\times_\rho V$ is the associated vector bundle. In section 3.2 of Morgan's book on Seiberg-Witten equations, there are given two different definitions of a covariant derivative $\nabla:\Omega^0(X;E)\to \Omega^1(X;E)$. Here are the two definitions:

1. For a section $\sigma \in \Omega^0(X;E)$, $x\in X$, and $\tau\in T_xX$, choose a path $\gamma$ in $X$ with $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma'(0)=\tau$, and choose a horizontal lift $\tilde{\gamma}$ to $E$. Then $\sigma(\gamma(t))=[\tilde{\gamma}(t),v(t)]\in E$ for some smooth path $v(t)\in V$. Define $\nabla(\sigma)(\tau)=[\tilde{\gamma}(0),v'(0)]\in E$.
2. Consider the differential $d\rho: \mathfrak{g}\to \text{End}(V)$. Fix a local trivialization $E|_U=U\times V$ and write $\sigma(u)=(u,\alpha(u))$, and define $\nabla(\sigma)=d\rho(\omega)(\alpha)+d\alpha$.

Why are these two definitions equivalent? I can't see how to show it, and I couldn't find any references concerning theses definitions (I've looked Lee's and Tu's books in DG).

Comment: I was thinking about this literally yesterday. I think what you want is in page 8 of [my very sloppy write-up](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/associated_connection.pdf).

Comment: In #2, where do you use $d\rho$ and what is $\omega$?

Comment: @Deane I fixed a typo for $d\rho$. $\omega$ is given in the first line.

Comment: @IvoTerek Thanks  a lot! Your note was very helpful. One question: In the third line of page 12 of your note, how do we get $\rho(g(x))\rho_*(\text{Ad}_{g(x)^{-1}}(A_\psi)_x(v))\rho(g(x)^{-1})=\rho_* ((A_\psi)_x)(v))$? I've understood your explanation that $\rho$ is a homomorphism and $g(x)\text{Ad}_{g(x)^{-1}} ((A_\psi)_x(v))g(x)^{-1}=(A_\psi)_x(v)$, but I can't see how these imply the above equation.

Comment: Right, $\rho$ and the conjugation $C_{\rho(g(x))}$ are homomorphisms. So we have that $$C_{\rho(g(x))} \circ \rho_\ast = \rho_\ast \circ {\rm Ad}_{g(x)}.$$The latter ${\rm Ad}_{g(x)}$ cancels the ${\rm Ad}_{g(x)^{-1}}$ inside $\rho_\ast$. Only $\rho_\ast((A_\psi)_x(v))$ remains.